# Linux: setup development localhost editable environment (permissions issue)

Tags: linux, apache, development-environment

*(First, I know this is a server related question, but, as it is development related I try Stackoverflow, as I didn't find a solution in other server admin sites)*

I have an Ubuntu distribution with a localhost setup in `/var/www/html/mysite` working properly. The problem I have is, when I edit files in this folder, I must do as root or `www-data` which is not completely ok, as I have to run every `mkdir` with `sudo -u` or use `chown` all the time, plus, my text editor (Sublime text) doesn't integrate properly with my Unity desktop.

I tried to setup localhost in my home dir but I found some problems and I don't like the idea so much.

As a better alternative I tried to have `mysite` in my home directory, owned by me and with permissions `drwxr-xr-x`, and create a symbolic link `/var/www/html/mysite` owned by `www-data`, but I get an error:

> 403 - You don't have permission to access / on this server.

This would be my preferred solution as having folders in my home dir would allow automatic sync through Dropbox.

As a second solution I have done, inside `/var/www/data`, `chown -R myuser:www-data mysite/`. This solves the edit permissions issue, but, I ask, is there any security or any other kind of issue?

Any ideas? How have you resolved this question?

PS: My user does belong to `www-data` group

Comment: as long as all this stuff is on localhost it is ok.